# sleep not working (error) on Win7

Tags: vbscript, wsh

This is my code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^r"
WshShell.Sleep 1000
```

The error message says:

> Object doesn't support Method: WshShell.Sleep

The `SendKeys` in the line above is working!

Comment: The slightest bit of effort would reveal that it's `wscript.sleep` nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like that:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^r"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
```

For more info about **[WScript.Sleep](http://ss64.com/vb/sleep.html)**